# NULL elements in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, null, nsmutablearray

I have a problem...
IN my MuttableArray have N element, but all elements is null

```
.h
        @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {
            NSMutableArray *listProjectPost;
        }

@property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listProjectPost;

.m
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize  listProjectPost;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.listProjectPost release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.listProjectPost = [NSMutableArray array];

// loop code
// current element
            currentNews *dop = [[currentNews alloc] init];
            [self.listProjectPost addObject:[dop createElement:node]];
            [dop release];
}
```

in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
currentNews *dop = [self.listProjectPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [dop getTitle];
...
}
```

all ok in top view (view when creating)
but next index i have error - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

sorry for my english

Comment: I poorly explained.
initialization table, I rendered the 5 elements (ie CurrentNews not null)

but when I start flipping the table (bottom) then vyleaet error and an array of currentNews zero (actually there and every element of 34 null, and must be a specific element)

with which it may be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store a null value in an Objective-C array, use `[NSNull null]`. You should check `[drop createElement:node]` to see if it is nil before adding it to your array.